# In Facebook Graph API - Is LIMIT parameter realy functional?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, limit, feed, facebook-graph-api-v2.2

I'm trying to collect all the posts of my company page with this kind of query

https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2//feed?**limit=250**&fields=id,type,status_type,comments{id},likes{id},shares

Problem is that I'm not collecting all posts.
I will have a better result with **limit=20** and some time with **limit=100**

Most of the pages (from the pagination mechanism point of view) will not have 100 items.

I know some posts may not be exposed because of privacy settings.
My issue is that a call with limit=20 is not returning once going through pagination the same amount of data as limit=250.

How could it be?

How providers of Facebook Analytics can garanty the quality of data they collect ?

Answer (score 1):

The Facebook graph api only allow the max of 100 items per request, despite you specify more than that.

Answer (score 0):

Afaik the limit parameter is indeed buggy. But 250 would be a very high value, there is a max value for the parameter too - i assume it depends on the API call how high it is, could be fixed too.

Better don´t use limit at all and use paging to get more results: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.2#paging